# How can we setup DB and ORM for the absence of Data Consistency requierement?

Tags: sql, hibernate, caching, web, proxy

Imagine we have a web-site which sends write and read requests into some DB via Hibernate. I use Java, but it doesn't matter for this question.

Usually we want to read the fresh data from DB. But I want to introduce some delay between the written data becomes visible to reads just to increase the performance. I.e. I dont need to "publish" the rows inserted into DB immediately. Its OK for me to "publish" fresh data after some delay.

How can I achieve it?

As far as I understand this can be set up on several different tiers of my system.

1. I can cache some requests in front-end. Probably I should set up proxy server for this.  But this will work only if all the parameters of the query match.
2. I can cache the read requests in Hibernate. OK, but can I specify or estimate the average time the read query will return stale data after some fresh insert occurred? In other words how can I control the delay time between fresh data becomes visible to the users? 
   Or may be I should use something like a memcached system instead of Hibernate cache?
3. Probably I can set something in DB. I dont know what should I do with DB. Probably I can ease the isolation level to burst the performance of my DB.

So, which way is the best one?

And the main question, of course: does the relaxation of requirements I introduce here may REALLY help to increase the performance of my system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your main question - caching is one of the most effective ways of increasing both performance and scalability of web applications which are constrained by database performance - your application may or may not fall into this category.

In general, I'd recommend setting up a load testing rig, and measure the various parts of your app to identify the bottleneck before starting to optimize.

The most effective cache is one outside your system - a CDN or the user's browser. [Read up](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#BROWSER) on browser caching, and see if there's anything you can cache locally. Browsers have caching built in as a standard feature - you control them via HTTP headers. These caches are very effective, because they stop requests even reaching your infrastructure; they are very efficient for static web assets like images, javascript files or stylesheets. I'd consider a proxy server to be in the same category. The major drawback is that it's hard to manage this cache - once you've said to the browser "cache this for 2 weeks", refreshing it is hard.

The next most effective caching layer is to cache (parts of) web pages on your application server. If you can do this, you avoid both the cost of rendering the page, and the cost of retrieving data from the database. Different web frameworks have different solutions for this.

Next, you can cache at the ORM level. Hibernate has a pretty [robust implementation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache), and it provides a lot of granularity in your cache strategies. [This article](http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/03/24/understanding-caching-in-hibernate-part-three-the-second-level-cache/) shows a sample implementation, including how to control the expiration time. You get a lot of control over caching here - you can specify the behaviour at the table level, so you can cache "lookup" data for days, and "transaction" data for seconds.

The database already implements a cache "under the hood" - it will load frequently used data into memory, for instance. In some applications, you can further improve the database performance by "de-normalizing" complex data - so the import routine might turn a complex data structure into a simple one. This does trade of data consistency and maintainability against performance.

Comment: Thanks Neville! When speaking of the browser caching, do you mean caching only requests made by the browser owner OR you advice downloading and placing the results of the most popular requests to the server to client side?

Comment: I've included a link to explain the "general" web caching strategies. All browsers have a cache built in; you control this via HTTP headers.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your architecture correct you have client -> server -> database server

Answers to each point

1. This will put the burden on the client to implement the caching if you only use your own client I would go for this method.  It will have the side effect of improving client performance possibly and put less load on the server and database server so they will scale better.
2. Now caching on the server will improve scalability of the database server and possibly performance in the client but will put a memory burden on the server.  This would be my second option
3. Implement something in the database.  At this point what are you gaining? the database server still has to do work to determine what rows to send back. And also you will get no scalability benefits.

So to sum up I would cache at the client first if you can if not cache at the server.  Leave the DB out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks Dreamwalker! By caching in front-end I mean not browser, but cache in web-server tier of my app. For example: cache responses to some popular http requests to my server. Without even asking Hibernate about this. As for DB option - I just dont know whether  some kind of cache exists in standart relational DBs, such as PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: been browser based you can also add HTTP caching into the mix to cut down traffic to the web server.  So number 2 is more your situation I don't see a web server as a client :).  Query's are cached but you would need to code it so it doesn't hit the new data and also index on the same column (That is been very simplistic)